# Strange behavior of sorted itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm struggling to understand how `groupby` from the package `itertools` works.  I am inputting a sorted list, but I cannot access the individual groups.

For example:

```
import itertools
sorted_types =   [ dict(type="a", value=":-o" ),
                  dict(type="a", value=":-P" ),
                  dict(type="b", value=":-(" ),
                  dict(type="b", value=":-|" ),
                ]
groups = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_types, lambda x: x["type"]):
    groups.append(list(g))
    print k, list(g), len(list(g))
print groups
```

The output of this program is

```
a [] 0
b [] 0
[[{'type': 'a', 'value': ':-o'}, {'type': 'a', 'value': ':-P'}], [{'type': 'b', 'value': ':-('},   {'type': 'b', 'value': ':-|'}]]
```

If the size `list(g)` is 0, why is the `groups` variable being updated?

I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3):

The `g` returned by `groupby` is an iterator, as noted in the [`groupby` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby().

Once you call `list(g)` on it the first time, you've exhausted it. All the subsequent times you call it, you're getting an empty list back, because you're calling `list()` on an exhausted iterator.

To get the output you expect, store the list first, then use it:

```
import itertools
sorted_types =   [ dict(type="a", value=":-o" ),
                  dict(type="a", value=":-P" ),
                  dict(type="b", value=":-(" ),
                  dict(type="b", value=":-|" ),
                ]   
groups = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_types, lambda x: x["type"]):
    l = list(g)
    groups.append(l)
    print k, l, len(l)
print groups
```

Output:

```
a [{'type': 'a', 'value': ':-o'}, {'type': 'a', 'value': ':-P'}] 2
b [{'type': 'b', 'value': ':-('}, {'type': 'b', 'value': ':-|'}] 2
[[{'type': 'a', 'value': ':-o'}, {'type': 'a', 'value': ':-P'}], [{'type': 'b', 'value': ':-('}, {'type': 'b', 'value': ':-|'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `list(g)` consumes `g`, so calling it a second time during the same `groupby()` iteration returns an empty list.

To fix, call it once and keep the result:

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_types, lambda x: x["type"]):
    l = list(g)
    groups.append(l)
    print k, l, len(l)
print groups
```